# Visual Studio 2022 "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" Error on MVC 4 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2022

I'm developing my old MVC 4 project on Visual Studio 2022. But when I try to "add view" or "add area", "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error occurs. It only happens in VS2022. VS2019 is OK.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my issue video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTY4xTyJp1w

Comment: For bugs in VS, use the feedback system to report the issue.  This is the best way to inform the product team and get a fix.

Comment: @Jimmy Thanks! I will try to report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft fixed the issue. They will publish it on the next release.

The details: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Arithmetic-operation/1645772?entry=myfeedback

**Edit**:

Heh he... They fixed it. It works well on 17.1.0 Preview. I'm waiting for the 17.1.0 Release version now. =)

You can use Preview version until the release version publish.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, updating to release version VS2022 17.2.6 failed to resolve the error for me. Rolling back to VS2019 16.11.17 allowed me to continue development without the issue.